# Android Custom Listener

Tags: android

Today I meet with a question about custom listener. I have try to search and think for a long time, but I have not find answer. I'm come here for help. The question is that How to transfer data between Activities by Android Custom Listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not transfer data between activities through custom listener because only one activity is active. Android application shouldn't work like that.

Use `Bundle` to send data between activities instead.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", yourValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

Inside `YourActivity`:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

Comment: I know the method.What I mean is that there are two interfaces,every interface has Button and EditText and interface belongs to own activity.When I click the Button of the first Activity,jump to the second activity.Then transfer data from the activity to the first activity.I want to implement it by Listener.Thank You !

Comment: You can't do that by listener. If you want to send data back, use `startActivityForResult` instead and handle the result in `onActivityResult` callback.

Comment: In addition to this method,there are other method?

Comment: No. If you have activities A and B and you launch A -> B, now B is on the top of the **stack** and you cannot interact with A while it's not active. You can send data via listeners or broadcasts wherever you need but not to activity A. To send data back to activity A you should use `onActivityResult`

Comment: How can I send data via custom listeners?Before activity B finish,transfer data to activity A via custom listeners.

Comment: You can send data via custom listener just like you do it in java, create an interface, add a method, create a class that implements this interface, create object of that class, pass it to `Activity` B, call method on the object when you need it. But again, you can call a method on a listener object, but it will not be `Activity` A. You cannot use custom listeners to pass data between activities.

Answer (score 0):

Listener is for listening the event only not for data transferring.But You can set/get value by listening to the event from listener.

If I was in your condition i would use bundle to transfer data from one activity to another activity as:
From ActivityA(send data from this activity)

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
bundle.putString("USER_NAME", userName);
//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

And get Data in ActivityB as:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
//Extract the data…
String venName = bundle.getString("USER_NAME");
```